# Can the compiler check that the first string parameter is less than the second string parameter?

Tags: typescript

I figure this is a long shot because I wouldn't know where to begin with this one. I know I can check if the first parameter comes after the second with this code:

```
    first
      .toString()
      .toLowerCase()
      .localeCompare(second.toString().toLowerCase()) >= 0
```

That's nice, but I'd rather have this check occur at compile time. Is such a thing possible in typescript? How could it be done?

Comment: Depends on what `first` and `second` can be, and aside from the most trivial cases, it'd be difficult. And if you were to do it purely at compile-time, it'd have no effect at runtime. You're probably best off leaving it as is.

Comment: @CertainPerformance they could be any string or regex. Actually, my situation is that I don't need it at runtime. This is test code and I want to enforce a certain order for myself when I read it.

Comment: if it's always a string, the `.toString()` call is misleading :?

Comment: @Khez oh god. My bad. It's `string | Regex`. Sorry, I forgot.

Comment: If the string is a constant type (eg typed as `'foo'` and not `string`), it'd be possible but pretty involved, involving recursive template literal types ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67184772)). If it's `string` only (or `string | Regex`), then it's impossible.

Comment: @CertainPerformance You have convinced me to leave it as a runtime check :)

Comment: The value of string can be known only at runtime.